# IIS 7.5 Logs and ASP.Net 404 Custom Pages

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, http-status-code-404

I want to make a custom 404 page for my site but I want to log all the normal information into my IIS 7.5 logs like the default 404 deals with so my Statics program can tell me things like what page got the 404 error, what was the referring URL to that broken page, and more. Do I have to do anything special on my 404 page to do this or has ASP evolved enough to automatically do logging for me if I return a 404 status code?

Comment: Why don't you try it and then if it doesn't seem to work then ask your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you handle the errors determines how the errors will show up in the logs/responses.  If you simply use custom error pages, it will show up no different in the log than if you had used the OOTB pages.  If, however, you are writing an ASP.NET application, and handle/bury the exception, nothing will show up in the logs.

If you are writing a .NET application, this [blog post](http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/Handling-404-errors-with-ASPNET.aspx) provides a pretty good overview on how to properly handle errors for SEO.

Comment: I am not talking about the default Application logs but the IIS w3c logs.

Comment: Going over that blog post I was able to adapt it to deal with just the 404 and after testing it is passing all the information I need while presenting a nice 404 message. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Custom Error pages can be implemented in many different ways. The "worst" way are those that return a 301 redirection to "NotFound.aspx" (or similar), which will, of course, return a 200 status code. Unfortunately the IIS Manager actually lets you specify this method. If you're finding your 404s and 500s aren't being logged then check out this setting first.

Error pages, regardless of their implementation, must not issue any redirection and must set the status code to 404, that way IIS's logger will log it accordingly (IIS inspects the headers of all outgoing responses and uses that to populate the log).

Comment: Do you have a link to a site that details how to setup everyting from IIS to web.config to the code behind? I can not find any decent links on google and have setup the following code in web.config and code behind but still get the default 404 page.

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Status = "404 Not Found";
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
    }

Comment: Sorry for the bad code formating I cant get the "backticks" or the indent by 4 spaces to format it